# Javascript confirm multiple changes

Tags: javascript

I want to alert the user to any changes made in 4 fields. Currently the script works 1 at a time. If 1 or 4 changes have been made, it only alerts to the first one and skips the others. I would like it all displayed in one Confirm box.

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var w = document.getElementById("item_name");
if (w.value != w.defaultValue)
{
  return confirm('Update Item Name. Continue?');
}

var x = document.getElementById("item_brand");          
if (x.value != x.defaultValue)
{
return confirm('Update Item Brand. Continue?');
}

var y = document.getElementById("department_id");           
if (!y.options[y.selectedIndex].defaultSelected)
{
return confirm('Update Item Department. Continue?');
}

var z = document.getElementById("vendor_part_num");         
if (z.value != z.defaultValue)
{
return confirm('Update Vendor Part Number. Continue?');
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to ask for each field individually, so you could first check them all, then ask the user, like this

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var strQuestion = '';
var bStChanged = false;
var w = document.getElementById("item_name");
if (w.value != w.defaultValue)
{
  bStChanged = true;
  strQuestion = strQuestion + 'Update Item Name.' + String.fromCharCode(13);
}

var x = document.getElementById("item_brand");          
if (x.value != x.defaultValue)
{
  bStChanged = true;
  strQuestion = strQuestion + 'Update Item Brand.' + String.fromCharCode(13);
}

var y = document.getElementById("department_id");           
if (!y.options[y.selectedIndex].defaultSelected)
{
  bStChanged = true;
  strQuestion = strQuestion + 'Update Item Deparment.' + String.fromCharCode(13);
}

var z = document.getElementById("vendor_part_num");         
if (z.value != z.defaultValue)
{
  bStChanged = true;
  strQuestion = strQuestion + 'Update Vendor Part Number.' + String.fromCharCode(13);
}

if (bStChanged)
{
  return confirm(strQuestion + ' Continue?')
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the `validation` behavior from how you want to manage it, like confirming or anything:

```
var fields = {
    "item_name": "Item Name",
    "item_brand": "Item Brand",
    "department_id": "Item Department",
    "vendor_part_num": "Vendor Part Number"
};
var confirmFields = [];

function isFieldChanged(elmId){
    var elm = document.getElementById(elmId);
    if(!elm){
        return;
    }
    var isChanged = false;
    if(elm.tagName.toLowerCase() == "select"){
        isChanged = !elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].defaultSelected;
    }
    else{
        isChanged = (elm.value !== elm.defaultValue);
    }
    if(isChanged){
        confirmFields.push(elm.id);
    }

    //in case you want to use the isChanged in another use case
    return isChanged;
}

function validateForm(){
    confirmFields = [];
    Object.keys(fields).forEach(isFieldChanged);
    if(confirmFields.length){
        var changes = confirmFields.map(function(fieldName){
            return fields[fieldName];
        }).join(", ");
        return confirm('Update ' + changes + '. Continue?');
    }
    return true;
}
```

This way you actually split the form and field validations, and also you ask for user's confirmation just once.

The other tricky point is instead of using `forEach` in `validateForm` function you can also iterate manually through fields:

```
    for(var key in fields){
        if(fields.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            isFieldChanged(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like what you did there, but, it's recognizing the default as changes and ignoring the changes. Plus it's completely ignoring the select field.

Comment: @user3556177: my bad! I had missed the select nodes, I just updated and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the result of the previous check to the next one:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var continueAsking = true;
    var w = document.getElementById("item_name");

    if (w.value != w.defaultValue)
    {
      continueAsking = confirm('Update Item Name. Continue?');
    }

    var x = document.getElementById("item_brand");          
    if (continueAsking && x.value != x.defaultValue)
    {
      continueAsking = confirm('Update Item Brand. Continue?');
    }

    var y = document.getElementById("department_id");           
    if (continueAsking && !y.options[y.selectedIndex].defaultSelected)
    {
      continueAsking = confirm('Update Item Department. Continue?');
    }

    var z = document.getElementById("vendor_part_num");         
    if (continueAsking && z.value != z.defaultValue)
    {
      continueAsking = confirm('Update Vendor Part Number. Continue?');
    }

    return continueAsking;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this using jquery:

```
var defaults = { item_name:'', 
            item_brand:'', 
            department_id:'', 
            vendor_part_num:'' };

$('#confirm').on('click', function() {
  $('.check').each(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    var item_value = $(this).val();
    if( defaults[ item ] != item_value ) {
      alert(item + ' have changed');
    }
  });
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ce696/2/).